# Dynamically add prefix to spark dataset columns while doing join without specifiying individual column names

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am joining two Spark datasets as follows

```
Dataset<Row> dataDF =  merc.as("merc").join(ded.as("ded"),col("merc.id").equalTo(col("ded.id")).and(
                                              col("merc.mid").equalTo(col("ded.mid"))), "outer");
```

Both the datasets have same schema.

> Schema :id, mid, pid, zid

The dataDf  schema has `id, mid, pid, zid, id, mid, pid, zid` since i am doing outer join.

While trying to write in parquet format, I am getting below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) when inserting into file:/xyz: `id`, `mid`, `pid`, `zid`;
```

How can I rename columns (may be add prefix with tablename e.g merc.id) dynamically without specifying individual columns for dataDF while doing join so that schema of dataDF can be

`ded.id, ded.mid, ded.pid, ded.zid, merc.id, merc.mid, merc.pid, merc.zid`

Answer (score 0):

probably try renaming befor join for one of the table.

eg:in pyspark

```
 merc.alias("merc").select(col("id").alias("merc_id"),col("mid").alias("merc_mid"))\
                   .join(ded.alias("ded"),[(col("merc.merc_id")==col("ded.id")) \
                                  & (col("merc.merc_mid")==(col("ded.mid")))], how="outer")
```